# in R how to compute means of increasing number/order of sequence

Tags: r

Suppose I have a data frame which is something like the one below:

```
mydataframe <- data.frame(x=1:10, y=c(2,4,6,8,11,14,17,19,22,29))

plot(mydataframe$y, type = "l", lwd="3", col="red")
```

What I am trying to do is to compute averages such as average of y[1]=2, y[1,2]=3 and so forth...

```
y   Avg  basically
2   2      2/1
4   3     (2+4)/2
6   4     (2+4+6)/3
8   5     (2+4+6+8)/4
11  6     (2+4+6+8+11)/5 
14  8        so forth
17  9        
19  10
22  11
29  13
```

I was trying using for loop, but I know I am wrong and won't get the desired result...

```
for (i in 1:length(mydataframe$x)) {
  print (mean(mydataframe$y[i]))
}
```

Can someone help please? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use `cumsum` divided by `x`,

```
cumsum(mydataframe$y)/mydataframe$x
#[1]  2.000000  3.000000  4.000000  5.000000  6.200000  7.500000  8.857143 10.125000 11.444444 13.200000
```

Answer (score 3):

We can use `cummean` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
mydataframe$basically <- cummean(mydataframe$y)
```

Comment: thanks @akrun, your answer is awesome. but I think, since it will use another package, `dplyr`, i can not accept the answer as of now. please do not feel offended but surely your answer is of much help as well.